# Split Feed Based on Number

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have a feed that I want to split based on the number of the item. For example, split it so it outputs items 5 - 10 or 4 - 12. I'm new to Yahoo Pipes, so is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Look at the built in example demos for the modules called  "Truncate" and "Tail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tail and revese operators

exemple to extract 5- 10 items 
you have a feed :
1 / 2 / ...

- reverse
  => ... / 2 / 1
- tail 10 
  => 10 / ... / 1
- reverse
  => 1 / ... /10
- tail 6
  -> 5 / 6 / 7 / 8 / 9 / 10